# send multiple assets in one transaction

Tags: wallet, nft, transaction, asset

I have 2 wallets.
I have about 10 assets (tokens, cnfts) besides ADA in each wallet.
I would like to send the assets from one wallet to the other to consolidate them.
Can I do this in one transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. A single cardano transaction may contain *multiple inputs per address from multiple wallets*, so long as the **transaction contains a signature for every unique address from which a UTXO is being consumed.**

For example, if all of your ADA/assets that you wish to consolidate are spread across 5 UTXO's in a single address, you can create a transaction where all 5 are consumed in 5 TX-inputs, and output to a single UTXO sent to the new wallet. If no change is being sent back to the original wallet/address, such a transaction would contain 5 inputs and one output. This transaction would require only one signature associated with the address whose UTXO's are being consumed. If there are multiple input addresses, you would need a signature from each input address.

I provided an example in [this](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/sign-transaction-with-multiple-inputs) post.

Let me know if you need further clarification or a different example! :)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm glad this is possible, but it sounds confusing. Would I do this directly from my wallet, or is this done with a CLI tool?

Comment: if you are using a frontend wallet like Yoroi or Daedalus, I don't think there is an option for multi-wallet (batched) transactions. You could however consolidate assets from a single wallet in one transaction by sending all of the assets to a single address on your new wallet. If however you do need to construct multi-wallet transactions, `cardano-cli` or `cardano-wallet` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use a light wallet client or do this using the cardano-cli?

If you’re looking to just get the one time task done, I’d recommend [this](https://ccvault.io/).

Go to Send -> Input an address -> Input an amount -> Add assets to the same transaction -> Submit.